# Calculate time to launch from arrival time and travel time

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to calculate a launch time from the given arrival and travel time. I have looked into DateTime, but I'm not quite sure how I would do it. I am using monthCalander to get the arrival dateTime in the format below.

```
Example:

Arrival_time = 20/03/2013 09:00:00
Travel_time = 00:30:00

Launch_time = Arrival_time - Travel_time

Launch_time should equal: 20/03/2013 08:30:00
```

Can someone show me a simple way to achive this please. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a mix of the DateTime object and a timespan. I've mocked up a small console app to demonstrate this.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Datetime checker";
            Console.Write("Enter the date and time to launch from: ");
            DateTime time1 = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the time to take off: ");
            TimeSpan time2 = TimeSpan.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            DateTime launch = time1.Subtract(time2);
            Console.WriteLine("The launch time is: {0}", launch.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I ran using your example inputs and got the expected output, this should serve your needs.

I hope this helps speed you on your way in time for launch :)

Comment: I will also look at your program. Thanks for trying to help, it's greatly appriciated.

Comment: Your soulution cracked it for me straight away. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx):

```
DateTime arrivalTime = new DateTime(2013, 03, 20, 09, 00, 00);
// Or perhaps: DateTime arrivalTime = monthCalendar.SelectionStart;

TimeSpan travelTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
DateTime launchTime = arrivalTime - travelTime;
```

If for some reason you can't use `MonthCalendar.SelectionStart` to get at the DateTime and you only have the string available, you can parse it into a DateTime as follows (for that particular format):

```
string textArrivalTime = "20/03/2013 09:00:00";
string dateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

DateTime arrivalTime = DateTime.ParseExact(textArrivalTime, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I will try your suggestion right now.

Comment: How would I modify this to accept the format in my original post? Would I use split() in some way?

Comment: I think MonthCalendar should give you a DateTime back that you can use directly, rather than you having to parse some text. You should be able to use `MonthCalendar.SelectionStart`, if only one date is selected. Otherwise, look into `DateTime.ParseExact()` where you can specify the date format that you want to parse.